# Background for a page thats 90% white and 10% image that scales

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to do the following and until now I neither got it to work on my own nor did I find something similar online. I am building a page that will not be scrollable and I want a white background but with a [rainbow stripe](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As4CoEQdBAklhOUSA5ZMXn-KPtDJeg?e=xi6n5K) at the bottom of the page.

I kinda got it to work like this with a div (I tried it as a background for the whole page, but it blurres because css doesn't crop the image, it compresses it):

```
.rainbow {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: white url('../img/rainbow.jpg') no-repeat bottom fixed;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

But the problem with this code is, that it does not scale properly: Passing a certain point the image isn't visible all the way, because it gets cut on both sides(left and right) the hight works.

I hope y'all know what I want to do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gradient as background and no need image or a lot of code:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right,
      blue                  calc(1*100%/6),
      green  calc(1*100%/6) calc(2*100%/6),
      yellow calc(2*100%/6) calc(3*100%/6),
      orange calc(3*100%/6) calc(4*100%/6),
      red    calc(4*100%/6) calc(5*100%/6),
      purple 0) 
   bottom/100% 10% no-repeat;
    
}
```

Or if you want it inside a fixed element:

```css
.box {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:10%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right,
      blue                  calc(1*100%/6),
      green  calc(1*100%/6) calc(2*100%/6),
      yellow calc(2*100%/6) calc(3*100%/6),
      orange calc(3*100%/6) calc(4*100%/6),
      red    calc(4*100%/6) calc(5*100%/6),
      purple 0); 
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using an image, you could achieve that with HTML and CSS.

```css
.rainbow {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.color {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
}

#green {
  background: green;
}

#yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

#orange {
  background: orange;
}

#red {
  background: red;
}

#purple {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
  <div id="blue" class="color"></div>
  <div id="green" class="color"></div>
  <div id="yellow" class="color"></div>
  <div id="orange" class="color"></div>
  <div id="red" class="color"></div>
  <div id="purple" class="color"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

height: 10%; will scale the thickness. If you want the thickness consistent when you resize, just use px instead. I found 75px was about the same size as 10% when in full screen.
For the image, I just increased the width of your image to 2500x905 px This scaled nicely with no blur in both my monitors.

```
.rainbow {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: white url('http://foregotten.net/imgs/pen/rainbow1.jpg') no-repeat bottom fixed;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Foregotten/5yLev3bf/6/